# Why can calling communicate() on a pipeline component other than the last yield corrupted output?

Tags: python, grep, subprocess, pipe, popen

I want to count the occurrences of around 500 patterns in a large .fastq file (59 million lines). The patterns are all exactly 20 characters long.

In unix this would be a simple:

```
grep -F -o -f patterns.txt big_file.fastq | sort | uniq -c
```

However, I wish to avoid writing a temporary patterns file so I created a pipe using python's subprocess library:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p1 = Popen(["grep", "-F", "-o", "-f", "-", "big_file.fastq"], shell = False, stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr= STDOUT)
p2 = Popen(["sort"], shell = False, stdin = p1.stdout, stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT)
p3 = Popen(["uniq", "-c"], shell = False, stdin = p2.stdout, stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT)
```

I then call communicate() on this, providing an encoded io.StringIO file-like object as input (which I  is passed to the grep command using the '-'):

```
import io

patterns_file = io.StringIO("\n".join(patterns_list))
p3.communicate(input = patterns_file.read().encode('utf-8'))[0]
```

When I call communicate() on uniq like this, this works fine.

However, while testing I erroneously called it on the first part of the pipe:

```
p1.communicate(input = patterns_file.read().encode('utf-8'))[0]
```

This gave me completely wrong outputs, including matches that were shorter or longer than the expected 20 characters.

I don't understand why this is. Wouldn't calling communicate() on p1 only involve that part of the pipe and ignore the rest? Removing p2 and p3 caused p1 to grep correctly. I feel I am missing something about how Popen works.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's surprising to me that you redirect standard error to `STDOUT` in each of the processes.  You'd almost certainly do better with standard error going to standard error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate `Popen` objects, the subprocesses they refer to are immediately started. Thus, even if you only call `communicate()` on `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are also running.

Why does this matter? Because `p2` still has its stdin attached to the FIFO to which `p1` is writing its output!

If the `sort` operation on `p2` is still reading content at the same time you ask your Python program to read that same content directly, you end up with `p1`'s output divided between them. Hilarity can be expected to ensue: The only way reads being split between two programs *wouldn't* result in visibly corrupt data is if both `p2` and `communicate()` were reading blocks that were multiples of 20 bytes (while still small enough for the operating system to not split them into multiple syscalls); however, typical chunk sizes used for unbuffered reads are multiples of 4096, creating 4 bytes of offset from the record boundary each time a chunk is read.

---

By the way -- for *many* programs this wouldn't have as severe an effect, because FIFOs have a relatively small buffer; a program that writes a line of output for each line of input it reads would end up blocked on output very quickly, and thus would stop reading further input until its output is at least partially flushed. `sort` is an exception, because it needs to read all its input before it knows what its first line of output will be!

Comment: @mvucak, btw, I think I'm about done refining/editing this answer unless you have any follow-up questions or guidance on where it's unclear. Please let me know!

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! I think I understand: calling communicate() on p3 allows all of the output from p1 to reach p2 and p2 will sort correctly before passing everything to p3?

But calling it on p1 means we only get the output that DOESN'T get passed on to p2?

Comment: Exactly. Both we and p2 are reading p1's output, and any of it that p2 reads isn't available for us to read -- since each `write()` to a FIFO corresponds with only exactly one `read()`. (This is why the need for programs like `tee`, doing multiple `write()`s for each `read()`, exists).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I do have one more question. When I called `communicate()` on `p1`, a minority of the corrupted output was longer than 20 characters. The `grep -o` call only returns 20-character matches. Even if its output is split between `p2` and `communicate()`, shouldn't output lines be 20 characters at most? Is this happening because `p1`'s output is occasionally split precisely on a newline?

Comment: I'd expect you to get a mix of longer and shorter lines. BTW, if the "20 character" output mentioned above doesn't consider newlines, then we need to calculate the difference between the (typically) 4096-character buffers and the 21-character records. Assuming both processes are reading 4096 bytes at a time, the first read (whichever process completes it) would get 195 complete records and 1 stray extra byte; the *second* read would get the rest of that stray record (1 byte short, so 19 bytes of data and a newline), and at its end be two bytes short.

Comment: So, if read N finishes 10 bytes into a record (and thus *not* seeing that record's newline), and read N+1 (for a given program, so actually at a later offset in the file) starts with a record that's only three bytes in, you get a 27-byte record (10 from the first + 17-and-newline from the second).